# Differential equation growth problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

If a population of insects double each week and the initial number of the population is $500000$ if a predator kills $250000$ weekly what is the population function with respect to $t$ as $t$ with days.

What I tried the equation could be this $\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{2t}{7} p - \frac{1}{7}(250000) $ ?? 
Or is it just $p(t) = (500000)2^{\frac{t}{7}} - \frac{t}{7} 250000$ 
Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your equation and test it

$$ p(t) = (500000)2^{\frac{t}{7}} - \frac{t}{7}(250000) \tag{1} $$

At time $t=0$

$$ p(0) = (500000)2^{\frac{0}{7}} - \frac{0}{7}(250000) \\   500000 \tag{2} $$

and in one week we have

$$ p(7) = 500000 \cdot 2 - \frac{7}{7} \cdot 250000  \\   = 750000 \tag{3} $$

Which is what we would expect, yes it is right.

Comment: What about the differential equation if we want to put this problem as differential equation?

Comment: you take the derivative with respect to $t$ of the function $p(t)$ and you have $\frac{dp}{dt}$ if you just pop on wolfram alpha you should have it.

Comment: in terms of deriving a random differential equation that fits that..I have to think ..maybe in the morning..